# No audio on built in audio jacks.Audio only works through the audio output from HDMI connected monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, hdmi, speakers

As the question states, I can only hear the audio output through the monitor's audio output.
My rear audio jacks and my front jacks do not work.
I an running windows 10 1511, motherboard is a MSI B150m and GPU is GTX 1060.
When I plug a speaker or a headset into the rear or front panel jack, my realtek HD Audio manager recognizes the device and I task it as the appropriate device.
The jacks have not worked since I first build it a couple days ago.
Any fixes??

EDIT: Monitor is LG 22MP58VQ and when is mention rear jacks, i mean the motherboard jacks(the green,black,etc) and the front jack means the one in the front of the case.

Comment: We need more information. What brand and type is your monitor, and where exactly are these audio jacks located? pc or monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the speaker icon in the notification area. 
Select “Playback devices” choose the  device you want sound output from...
Default device is speakers.
Yours probably set to something like HDMI.

Comment: This will likely lead you to the solution, although I've found once I actually had to uninstall the 'HDMI digital audio output' device from device manager to force sound out of the analog jack.